# initializing pointer to protected member functions

Tags: c++, initialization

I have this problem:

In the header file:

```
class D : public B
{
//...
private:
    typedef char* (B::*psbposfun_t)() const;

    static psbposfun_t ms_aposf[2][3];
//...
};
```

In the source file:

```
D::psbposfun_t D::ms_aposf[2][3] = 
{
    {
        &B::fa1,
        &B::fa2,
        &B::fa3
    },
    {
        &B::fb1,
        &B::fb2,
        &B::fb3
    }
};
```

The compiler complains that the fa1 ... fb3 methods are protected.
Indeed they are protected in B but I am initializing a member that belongs to D, which derives from B.

I tried initializing ms_aposf within the class (D) but the compiler complains it is not the place to initialize it.

So besides implementing a one-shot initialization in the constructor, would someone know how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Why are you having pointers to member methods? There are more elegant and safer ways to achieve the desired results. You are sort of undermining the whole point of OOP

Comment: Yes! Why are you using C++ in the first place! (scnr)... the example compiles with VS2013, but of course the member functions must be const. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: And, yes, making the functions public satisfies gcc. That does not look correct, although it's pretty esoteric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `D::` instead:

```
D::psbposfun_t D::ms_aposf[2][3] = 
{
    {
        &D::fa1,
        &D::fa2,
        &D::fa3
    },
    {
        &D::fb1,
        &D::fb2,
        &D::fb3
    }
};
```

Since `D` is inheriting these functions, they are accessible through `D`, but usable as `B::` pointers.

Comment: God! So simple I should remove my question!

Comment: @MaitreBart: I thought it was an interesting question.  The way that protected access works isn't necessarily obvious.  It isn't as simple as "only this class or derived classes can access it".  It is more like "base class members are allowed to be treated as private derived class members for the sake of access".